# Calling .Net script from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net

Is it possible to call local .Net script on client side from JavaScript?

I would like to do it to perform printing PDF, without a preview.

I know, that it's posiible to set browser into kiosk mode with auto printing, but it's not solution in my case - printing preview is being rendered and after that document is being printed. 
Rendering this preview every each time during printing receipt in kiosk is a big waste of time, so I would like to perform printing by system, which is much more faster.

Comment: Hey there! I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, have you got a .Net app that already creates a pdf? You may want to do some research as this might just be a case of creating an aspcore application and calling it via ajax (or framework specfic http call)

Comment: Hey! I have got app with backend written in Python (Django), which is deployed on server. This app is creating PDF and passing it to frontend.
Clients of this app are Kiosks. Those Kiosks are printing this PDF as a receipt. I would like to manage printing those receipts by client system (not in browser) and that's why I'm thinking about using .Net script on client side.

Comment: Do you mean [Script.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script.NET)?